# Nginx: Pass microtime header to uwsgi/django

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I'm running a django app behind Nginx with uwsgi. I would like to add a micro-time timestamp to each request. I'm having trouble figuring out how to piece this all together.

Comment: You need to send that timestamp to your uwsgi/code, or to the client ?

Comment: To the request -- as a header I can use in my Django view.

Answer (score 1):

Use `uwsgi_param` to send timestamp information from nginx.
Just add this line in your server's configuration :
`uwsgi_param Date $date_gmt;`

And then read `Date` header in your code.

Comment: Based on the docs for strftime, I'm thinking I can't use timefmt for micro-second precision in the timestamp?

Comment: Here's an example of using a perl module to accomplish this but I'd rather not add that complexity if there is any other way. https://serverfault.com/questions/165450/passing-a-timestamp-header-onto-upstream-servers-with-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Building on @skbly, I hadn't realized that in nginx 1.2.6 the $msec variable was made available in a request context:

```
uwsgi_param Mtime $msec;
```